# transforming content in xml having day,month,year into another xml to date of YYYYMMDD format using xslt

Tags: xslt

i have input xml as

```
           <content>
             <date>
            <day>14</day>
               <month>06</month>
                <year>2012</year>
               </date>
            </content>
```

want it to be converted into

```
          <content>
               <date>2012-06-14T00:00:00</date>
           </content>
```

xslt used

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
             <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

              <xsl:template match="content">
                 <content>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="date"/>
                 </content>
              </xsl:template>

                 <xsl:template match="date">
                  <date>
                   <xsl:variable name="year" select="year"/>
                   <xsl:variable name="month" select="month"/>
                   <xsl:variable name="day" select="day"/>
               <xsl:value-of select="$year" />-<xsl:value-of select="$month"/>-
                 <xsl:value-of  select="$day"/>

                 </date>   
                </xsl:template>        

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

i want date in YYYYMMDDTHH:MM:SS format as example 2012-06-15T02:52:37 how can i get it.Which function in xslt "1.0" pics the strings and take the format pattern as such. Can aynone please help me in getting the above format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <content>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </content>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="date">
  <date>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(year, '-', month, '-', day, 'T00:00:00')"/>
  </date>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<content>
    <date>
        <day>14</day>
        <month>06</month>
        <year>2012</year>
    </date>
</content>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<content>
   <date>2012-06-14T00:00:00</date>
</content>
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to get current time at the place of T00:00:00 is there any function as such in xslt 1.0 to get that

Comment: Not in XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 1.0 it is recommended to pass the current time  as an external, string parameter to the transformation. In XSLT 2.0 one can use the function `current-time()`